# Is there a colorblindness test for non-verbal children?

Tags: test, children-kids, color-blindness

The colorblindness tests that I have seen have all relied on getting a verbal answer from the test subject. Examples are "What number do you see in this picture?".

Most people can follow a test themselves online. But is there a way to check if a child is colorblind, if that child does not have the number or language skills required by these more common tests?

Comment: A child of what age? or age range?

Comment: 5, diagnosed with autism, and has a small number of words

Comment: What has your research revealed? When I google "color blindness test for non-verbal children" (without quotes), I get quite a few promising looking hits.

Comment: Ask them to [sort the color of M&Ms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYuscO9zTvQ) :)